# iOS - UINavigationBar transparent corners not all the time

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, ios6, uiappearance

I'm using a custom `UINavigationBar` which has transparent corners in the upper left and upper right. I'm using `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

This works great almost all the time but sometimes for instance when I show the keyboard instead of the transparent corners they become white, and when the keyboard slides back the corners go transparent again.

Does anyone have a clue what could cause this? (iOS 6, ARC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the cause of it. When I show the keyboard I slide my `UITableView` up. So I believe it is the `UITableView`s background that is showing behind the navigation bar. But I would think that the navigation bar wouldn't be affected of that?